# Jquery UI Date Picker Black Background Section in Safari

Tags: css, html, jquery-ui, datepicker, contact-form-7

I am using the [Contact Form 7](https://contactform7.com/) wordpress plugin and have enabled [fallback for HTML5 input types](https://contactform7.com/faq/does-contact-form-7-support-html5-input-types/) because the Safari does not support the date input type on the desktop.

The jquery-ui png images that came with contact form 7 were corrupt and required me to replace them from another source because they would not display correctly on Safari.

After solving the issue with the ui-icons I still have an area on the datepicker that shows up in black. I have inspected the code and cane not determine what element, styling or background image is responsible for the black area pictured below.

[image: Date Picker Black Background Bug]

The code for the widget is below -

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" style="position: fixed; top: 4px; left: 251px; z-index: 2; display: block;">
   <div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
      <a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all" data-handler="prev" data-event="click" title="Previous"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Previous</span></a><a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all" data-handler="next" data-event="click" title="Next"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Next</span></a>
      <div class="ui-datepicker-title"><span class="ui-datepicker-month">July</span>&nbsp;<span class="ui-datepicker-year">2018</span></div>
   </div>
   <table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th scope="col"><span title="Monday">M</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span title="Tuesday">T</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span title="Wednesday">W</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span title="Thursday">T</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span title="Friday">F</span></th>
            <th scope="col" class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Saturday">S</span></th>
            <th scope="col" class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Sunday">S</span></th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">1</a></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">2</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">3</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">4</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">5</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">6</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">7</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">8</a></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">9</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">10</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">11</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">12</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">13</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">14</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">15</a></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">16</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">17</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">18</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">19</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">20</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">21</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">22</a></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">23</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">24</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">25</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">26</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">27</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">28</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">29</a></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">30</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">31</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

I have traced through Safari's inspector a number of times and just have no idea what element I need to be looking at for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK simply try adding this:

```
.ui-widget-content {
    background: #fdfca5;
}
```

Comment: I ended up overriding this property by setting .ui-widget-content { background: #fff !important; }. Thanks for the easy solution.

Comment: @stats Regards.